# Using nginx proxy to redirect the content to another website

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, redirect

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 & Nginx for my websites.

I need help with the following question.

Let's say (on the same server) I have the following:

```
/home/website1/public_html/image_abc.webp
```

When people are accesing my 2nd website, I want to find a way to show them the image without using it's name, for exemple

```
/home/website2/public_html/image_abcd.webp
```

(I want this to be the same image as from the website1 path) but using other name.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if there are any Nginx directives that can achieve what you are after, but I believe you might want to look into using a symbolic link (symlink).

Maybe something like:

ln -s /home/website1/public_html/image_abc.webp /home/website2/public_html/image_abcd.webp

Comment: @ChrisNZ I know it's possible to do that, what I'm interested is if I'm able to use a directory from a path changing it's name without creating a new directory. Thank you for replying anyway!